# Bosch Dishwasher (smv50c00gb/06) Seems To Stop At Random

Tags: dishwasher

My bosch dishwasher seems to be stopping at random points, and never starts again, it needs to be plugged out and plugged back in and then it continues as normal.

It's integrated so I pulled it out, checked all pipes and ran it. It started fine and made noise, then It went very quiet after about half an hour.

I left it for another half an hour and then opened the door. It was warm inside and there was water in the bottom. The control panel didn't light up. I pressed the power button and nothing happened. So control panel is dead.

I unplugged it and plugged it back in. Opened the door and the clean display light was blinking (this light indicates a wash is in progress)

I closed the door and the cycle started again!
That cycle finished.

I ran it again but when it stopped there was water in the bottom and the control panel was completely dead. I unplugged it and plugged it back in again and the drying process continued.

Dishwasher is 2013 model.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't normal operation? Many dishwashers sound like they've stopped before continuing on to the next cycle.

Comment: Sometimes dishwashers will 'stop' to heat the water before continuing.

Comment: Fair point, I've made the post a bit clearer. Problem was discovered when I came down the morning after it was turned on and it had stopped mid cycle and there was no response from the control panel.